# How do I derive Hessian of this function and check for concavity?

Tags: mathematical-economics

The function is $f(K,L)= AK^{a}L^{b}$ on the set of points $(K,L)$ with $K\geq 0$ and $L\geq 0$, assuming $A>0$
How do I find the Hessian and check for concavity?

Comment: Do you know how to take a derivative?

Answer (score 7):

As @Herr K. stated, the beginning point is being able to take a derivative. The Hessian is a matrix equivalent to a second order derivative sometimes denoted as $\nabla^{2}$. Start by finding the gradient, $\nabla$ which is a vector of first order derivatives of every *variable* in the function. In your case, this would be
$$ \nabla=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{K}}  \\
   \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{L}} \\
  \end{array} } \right] =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   aAK^{a-1}L^{b}  \\
   bAK^{a}L^{b-1} \\
  \end{array} } \right] $$
The Hessian, would be the next (second) derivative of each of the above with respect to both variables and it takes the form:
$$ \nabla^{2}=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial{K}^2} & \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial{K}\partial{L}} \\
   \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial{L}\partial{K}} & \frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial{L}^2} \\
  \end{array} } \right] $$
Using whatever this would be in your case (left to you to compute) you can take the *determinant* of the resulting matrix and, with values for your parameters $a$ and $b$ (or at least their signs like with the other variables and parameters) you can determine whether the *determinant* is positive or negative and determine the concavity. If it is positive definite or positive semi-definite, this would imply either strict or non-strict convexity, respectively. If you don't know how to take a determinant it is simply dont by using a matrix say

$$ A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a_{1} & a_{2} \\
   a_{3} & a_{4} \\
  \end{array} } \right] $$
and then taking its determinant using the operation (without explanation for sake of brevity):
$$ A=
   {\begin{vmatrix}
   a_{1} & a_{2} \\
   a_{3} & a_{4} \\
  \end{vmatrix} } = a_{1}a_{4}-a_{2}a_{3} $$
Using this with the above, you should be able to figure the rest out and figure out whether or not its concave! (hint: for $a,b\geq 0$ and $a+b\leq1$ it is concave)

Comment: thank you for your help, sir.

Comment: Ofcourse! Could you accept the answer? It helps get the site off of Beta :)

Comment: " for a,b≤0 it is concave" This is wrong. a ≥ 0, b ≥ 0, and a + b ≤ 1 are required for the function to be concave on the stated domain( "the set of points $(K,L)$ with $K≥0$ and $L≥0$")

Comment: Oh oops my mistake, thank you for pointing that out.